# postgres stopped - how to restart?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

my postgresql (9.3.4) was running on Ubuntu, and suddenly stopped tonight. 
When I try to stop it, logged in as postgres, I get

```
~$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data stop;
pg_ctl: could not send stop signal (PID: 9242): No such process
```

when I try to start it, I get

```
$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -l /usr/local/pgsql  /data/postgresql.log start;
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
server starting
sh: 1: cannot create /usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.log: Read-only file system
```

So it doesn't start, and oddly enough, I get this complaint about postgresql.log too.

```
~$ ls -l /usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.log
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 351089 May 21 16:45 /usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.log
```

Strange that it complains about it being a read-only file system..? Even stranger, even as root, I cannot delete that file ...

```
~# rm /usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.log
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.log': Read-only file system
```

Same goes for the postmaster.pid

```
# rm -f /usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid': Read-only file system
```

How could I get my postgresql back to running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to fix the read only filesystem problem. I would ensure that my backups are good before trying to do anything else, you may end up having to use them anyway.

This could be as easy as

```
mount -o remount,rw filesystem
```

It may be much more complicated and involve having to [unmount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/umount.8.html) the filesystem and run filesystem checks via [fsck](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/fsck.8.html).

If for some reason you can't unmount the filesysem, you can try

```
touch /forcefsck
reboot
```

which will cause the system to run automatic filesystem checks as part of the boot sequent.

Did I mention backups - I hope you have known good ones.